# SslConfigs.SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CONFIG is removed in 3.4.0 kafka-client version

Tags: apache-kafka

SslConfigs.SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CONFIG is removed in 3.4.0 kafka-client version .WHat is the alternative provided for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting has been removed in Kafka 3.0.0 which released in 2021. It was deprecated since Kafka 1.0.0 (released in 2017!).

Since it's a broker-only configuration, it's not part of the public API so there's no public constants for it.

If you have code that depends on it, the simplest is probably to just hard code the setting name, `ssl.client.auth`. That value is now in `BrokerSecurityConfigs` which is not part of the public API so you should not depend on it in your applications.

Comment: Thank you I am now directly using it from BrokerSecurityConfigs